# Visual Studio Copy object values during debug and paste as populated class object

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Looking for an easier way to create test data in my unit tests in Visual Studio. Thinking it would be nice to be able highlight an object variable during debug, copy it's values, then open my unit test and Paste as to result in a populated new object instance with those values.

i.e.
Class Object

```
public class OrderHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

While viewing code during debug, copy the orderHeader object instance with values.

```
var ordeHeader = new OrderHeader()
{
    Id = 0,
    CustomerId = 2334,
    OrderDateTime = new Date()
};
```

In Unit Test paste object instance with values to result in something like the above:

```
{
    Id = 0,
    CustomerId = 2334,
    OrderDateTime = new Date()
};
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this? Ideally, to work with complex classes...i.e. in this case there could also be a collection of `OrderDetails` within `OrderHeader`.